# Как заменить все запятые, которые находятся внутри скобок?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, node.js

Как заменить все запятые, которые находятся в строке внутри скобок?

Например, есть строка:

`const str = 'яблоко, груша (1, 2)'`

Как её заменить на:

`яблоко, груша (1; 2)`

Comment: @Эникейщик да, ошибся, я имел в виду скобки

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте

```js
const str = 'яблоко, груша (1, 2)';
console.log( str.replace(/\([^()]*\)/g, (v) => v.replace(/,/g, ';')) );
// Или, если скобки в строке всегда сбалансированы, всегда парные
console.log( str.replace(/,(?=[^()]*\))/g, ';') );
```

`/\([^()]*\)/g` ищет все совпадения открывающей скобки, затем 0 и более символов, отличных от скобок, а затем закрывающую скобку, и в совпадении заменяет все запятые на точку с запятой с помощью второго регулярного выражения.

`/,(?=[^()]*\))/g` ищет все совпадения запятой, за которой есть 0 и более символов, отличных от скобок, а затем закрывающая скобка (этот текст не попадает в текст совпадения, так как `(?=[^()]*\))` — это блок предварительного просмотра вперёд). [См. демо](https://regex101.com/r/9R4wJ7/1).

Comment: спасибо огромное :)